# How to show a UITableViewCell as selected and still receive didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView which when `isEditing=YES` shows the cells with standard iOS selection circular 'checkbox' (see picture below). Some of these are 'bookmarked' via CoreData.

`tableView:willDisplayCell` reads from CoreData and sets
`cell.selected = YES;`  for the bookmarked cells.

Trouble is that these 'bookmarked' cells do not respond to

```
tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath
```

or

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

Whereas the same callbacks work fine on cells with `cell.selected=NO;`

The image shows a selected cell above a non selected cell.[image]

This is executed inside

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


 if (tableView.isEditing)
    { [cell setSelected:[self isCellFave:indexPath]];  }
```

Where `isCellFave` does

```
- (BOOL) isCellFave:(NSIndexPath *) indexPathIn
{
    BOOL isSelected = NO;
     // Check if this cell is a favourite 
    NSError *error;

    NSString * id = [self getIDFromIndexPath:IndexPathIn];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"( id = %@ )", id];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sort1" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [ManagedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if ([fetchedObjects count] !=0) //if a result then it is a fave
    {
        // When we set a cell as selected, all gestures stop working - so we can't deselect it.
        isSelected=YES;
    }
    return isSelected;
}
```

Comment: "reads from CoreData and sets cell.selected = YES;" sounds suspicious to me.  Can you post that code?

Comment: I posted my answer regarding your issue @Nick T

Comment: @handiansom thanks for pointing that out. But it doesn't really answer my issue which is why tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath  doesn't get called on deselect. My real issue is how to deselect a selected cell. Thanks for your partial answer.

Comment: @NickT I added new answer for deselecting. Try it out. It might help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use these codes.

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if (tableView.isEditing) { 
          [cell setSelected:[self isCellFave:indexPath]]; 
          [cell  addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(unselectRow:)]];
          }
      }
    }
```

Then add a tap gesture handler

```
- (void)unselectRow:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell  = (UITableViewCell *)     sender.view;
    cell.selected = NO;
}
```

Comment: Odd, it had 2 up-votes, I clicked to up-vote and it dropped to 1.

Comment: @NickT, either two people undid their votes within 5 minutes, or you undid your own vote.

Answer (score 0):

> Tapping to a selected cell will not call the
>   `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` tableView delegate method because that
>   cell is already selected. It will work/or get called if you tap the unselected cell.